# How to correct the removal of linebreak when echo prints the last caracter on a line?

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have this strange behavior when the echo prints the last character on the line:

```
<?php
$x="XXX";
?>
line A
line B <?=$x?>.
line C <?=$x?>
line D
line E <?php echo($x); ?>.
line F <?php echo($x); ?>
line G
```

Output:

```
line A
line B XXX.
line C XXXline D
line E XXX.
line F XXXline G
```

You can see line B and E have no problems.
However, line C and F miss the linebreak.

How to correct this behavior?

Ps: Output is not meant to be html.

Comment: Give a line break after the echos.

Comment: BTW the html output is: line A line B XXX. line C XXXline D line E XXX. line F XXXline G

Comment: My text editor placed a linebreak here.
I just don't understand why PHP doesn't respect the formating and skip the linebreak if it prints the last visible character of a line.

Comment: The parser must be deciding that a closing php tag on the end of a line should ommit the newline.

Comment: Is it possible to change the parser behavior?
This code sample will serve as a template and I don't want users to handle additional linebreaks.